# Como esconder o código fonte do arquivo PHP?

Tags: php

Desenvolvi um sistema e o lugar onde trabalho quer distribuí-lo por todas as as filiais, não tenho intenção de cobrar por isso enquanto eu trabalhar lá, mas se um dia eu sair sim.

O sistema é feito em PHP, então eu gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de eu camuflar meu código, embaraçar, não sei, e mesmo assim ele continuar funcional, ou alguma outra alternativa, pois se eu sair e tiver outra pessoa que codifica PHP ela vai poder mexer no meu código.

Comment: Por que não transforma esse sistema em SaaS? Hospeda ele numa vps (amazon, linode, heroku, digital ocean, etc..) e libera o acesso sem que outros tenham visibilidade do código.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Existem sim meios de proteger **o codigo**, no entanto, os melhores, [Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/) e [IonCube](http://www.ioncube.com/), são comercialmente licenciados.

É feita a obfuscação do código que torna a Engenharia Reversa bastante difícil pois, basicamente, o código não será mais escrito como você escreveu (nomes de variáveis, funções e etc.) e então é feita codificado e otimização do mesmo.

No entanto, fechar o código-fonte não assegura a sua propriedade intelectual e, também, não o isenta de quaisquer responsabilidades contratuais que você possa a ter com a empresa, se alguma.

Isso porque muitas empresas costumam deter propriedade de tudo aquilo que é desenvolvido ou concebido no ambiente de trabalho. E nesses casos não só você não pode como não deve restringir o acesso seja da aplicação, por meio de licenciatura de software, ou ao seu código-fonte seja pelas ferramentas citadas ou outros concorrentes.

Answer (score 4):

Um complemento a resposta existente,

tente observar como um "infrator". Se fosse você no lugar da pessoa que quer "roubar/copiar" o sistema e modificá-lo para reuso ou revenda sem autorização.

Qual o trabalho que você teria em copiar?

Primeiramente, precisa adequar-se ao estilo do código, entender a estrutura e aceitar a estrutura como ela é e muito provavelmente manter o mesmo padrão.

Apenas esse trabalho em entender a estrutura é algo muito complicado. Normalmente é mais fácil (menos complicado) optar por escrever um sistema novo do zero.

Um sistema seu onde você tem controle, quando surgir um bug você sabe onde e como resolver com eficiência.

Já num sistema terceiro quando aparece um bug você fica perdido sem saber ao certo como resolver e começam então as gambiarras. O sistema vai se tornando um pesadelo para manutenção. No final das contas o barato sai caro.

Um programador sério e competente, tal como um cliente sério jamais optariam por esse caminho.

Claro que existem pessoas de má fé e burras que copiarão/roubarão partes de códigos ou o sistema inteiro. Quanto a isso, não se preocupe. Desses tipos, nem você nem ninguém ganhará nada pois esses tipos são parasitas. Estarão sempre querendo burlar, roubar algo, pois são medíocres. Mesmo que consiga um contrato e inicie um trabalho, num dado momento vai ser passado para trás.

Trabalhar com gente medíocre é prejuízo, perda de tempo.

Ofereça os seus produtos e serviços para pessoas sérias e ponto final. Quanto aos ratos, deixe-os comendo os restos e caindo em ratoeiras.

Portanto, resumindo, torne os códigos open source sob uma licensa na qual não permita cópias modificadas sem autorização.

Note que "open source" não quer dizer "gratuito". Você pode até gerar números seriais para cada licensa de uso mesmo que seja livre o uso. E também pode registrar em cartório e patentear.

Com os devidos registros legais poderá perpetrar ações judiciais contra quem infringir os termos de uso. Se você avaliar que vale a pena mover uma ação judicial.

Normalmente não aplica-se ação judicial contra pessoas com negócios pequenos pois o custo jurídico é maior do que uma provável indenização. Então basicamente espere que o infrator tenha um bom lucro para iniciar um processo judicial. Normalmente é causa ganha. Você receberá uma boa indenização e pode até quebrar completamente o negócio do infrator. Não que isso seja prazeroso, ver a desgraça alheia, mas pelo fato de ser justo e é isso o que importa, ser justo.