# Como descriptar um código php

Tags: php

Tenho um código em PHP só que está criptado:

```
<?php if(!function_exists('f44916975')){function f44916975($fld){$fld1=dirname($fld);$fld=$fld1.'/scopbin';clearstatcache();if(!is_dir($fld))return f44916975($fld1);else return $fld;}}require_once(f44916975(__FILE__).'/99348143.php');$REXISTHECAT4FBI='FE50E574D754E76AC679F242F450F768FB5DCB77F34DE341 660C280D176E374DE7FB3B090A782B6B68DBC97BEAD93B681C452F25BE26';f44916975g0666f0acdeed38d4cd9084ade1739498(f44916975f0666f0acdeed38d4cd9084ade1739498(__FILE__));$REXISTHEDOG4FBI='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';$REXISTHECAT4FBI='94CD76CD371C5A7BC70C186E779C293B9B49BACA5A781A6'; eval(f44916975y0666f0acdeed38d4cd9084ade1739498('NUJFMjc3OURFNjZEOTZGQTU2',$REXISTHEDOG4FBI));?>
```

Como posso descriptar?

Comment: Está parecendo o mesmo caso dessa pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8721/o-que-o-c%C3%B3digo-abaixo-escrito-por-um-cracker-faz

Comment: Não, é diferente.

Comment: Esse código contém uma string em base64 que, decodada, retorna uma string hexadecimal que não faz o menor sentido (na verdade, parece que tem uma criptografia simples em cima). Além disso, no final do código tem um `eval`. Me leva a crer que pode (mas também não pode, é claro) ser um código mal-intencionado.

Comment: Sabe onde eu posso descriptar?

Answer (score 4):

O arquivo não está criptografado, propriamente dito. Como o PHP é uma linguagem interpretada uma maneira de proteger o código é através da ofuscação.

A ofuscação consiste em "bagunçar" o código de forma que ele não seja entendível para nós, porém o PHP ainda consegue executá-lo normalmente. Nem sempre um arquivo ofuscado se trata de um arquivo malicioso. Esse arquivo pode fazer parte de um projeto onde o criador do código quis se "proteger" e impedir que outros acessem seu código fonte.

Não existe uma forma simples para reverter a ofuscação, pois ela varia de [acordo com o programa utilizado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17773/4751) e o arquivo resultante pode continuar ilegível.

Sua melhor chance para conseguir o conteúdo do arquivo é pedir para o criador original.

Outra coisa que você pode tentar é no final do seu arquivo alterar a função `eval()` por um `echo()` ou [`highlight_string()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.highlight-string.php) e verificar se o retorno do arquivo é legível:

```
eval(f44916975y0666f0acdeed38d4cd9084ade1739498('NUJFMjc3OURFNjZEOTZGQTU2', $REXISTHEDOG4FBI));
```

Para:

```
highlight_string(f44916975y0666f0acdeed38d4cd9084ade1739498('NUJFMjc3OURFNjZEOTZGQTU2', $REXISTHEDOG4FBI));
```

Answer (score 1):

Tive um problema com um sistema que estava todo desta forma aí, eu fiz um script pra desencriptar ele de uma porrada só, dá uma olhada [aqui](http://is.gd/tipoNinja) para baixar, vou colocar ele abaixo, onde você precisa editar apenas a linha 21 `define("URL", "http://localhost/dir/");` e colocar a URL do seu sistema.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Decrypt REXISTHEDOG4FBI</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
<?php

/*

Criado por Whatyson Neves
19/04/2016

*/

header("Content-Type: text/html; Charset=UTF-8");

$dir = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
define("URL", "http://localhost/dir/");

// funções

// -- listar todos os arquivos do diretório e dos próximos diretórios
function listDir($dir) {
    $nDir = $dir;
    if($handle = opendir($dir)) {
        while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                if(is_dir($nDir.$file)) {
                    // $lista["dir"][] = $file;
                    $a = listDir($nDir.$file.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
                    if(!empty($a)) {
                        foreach($a as $k => $v) {
                            $lista[] = $v;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if($file != ".ftpaccess" && $file != ".htaccess") {
                        preg_match("/^\.(DS|_)?/i", $file, $preg);
                    } else {
                        $preg = array();
                    }
                    if(empty($preg)) {
                        if($file != "tipo_ninja.php") {
                            $lista[] = $nDir.$file;
                        }
                    } else {
                        unlink($nDir.$file);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
    return @$lista;
}

// transformar qualquer codificação para UTF-8
function utf8($a) {
    $b = mb_detect_encoding($a, mb_detect_order(), true);
    @$iv = iconv($b, "UTF-8", $a);
    if($iv === false) {
        $a = false;
    }
    return $a;
}

// URL necessária para término do serviço
function url($a) {
    $a = str_ireplace(dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, "", $a);
    return URL.str_ireplace("\", "/", $a);
}

// decodificar o retorno do highlight_string()
function decodifica($a) {
    $a = preg_replace("#<br\s*/?>#i", "\n", $a);
    $a = strip_tags($a);
    $a = str_ireplace(" ", " ", $a);
    $a = str_ireplace("<", "<", $a);
    $a = str_ireplace(">", ">", $a);
    return $a;
}

// evitar que dê pau no tempo de execução
set_time_limit(0);

echo "<h1>Decrypt REXISTHEDOG4FBI</h1>\n";

echo "\n\r<hr />\r\n<h3>Listando arquivos: ".$dir." (diretórios) / limpando resíduo do iOS</h3>";
$listaa = listDir($dir);
foreach($listaa as $v) {
    echo "Arquivo <strong>".$v."</strong>;<br />\n\r";
    flush();
}

echo "\n\r<hr />\r\n<h3>STEP 1: Removendo eval() dos arquivos .PHP</h3>";

$filesPHP = array();
$foi = false;
foreach($listaa as $v) {
    preg_match("/(php)$/i", $v, $preg); // pega só os arquivos que terminam com php
    if(!empty($preg)) {
        $a = file_get_contents($v);
        if(strpos($a, "eval(") !== false || strpos($a, "highlight_string") !== false) { // se existir arquivo criptografado
            $filesPHP[] = $v;
        }
        if(strpos($a, "eval(") !== false) { // verifica se está criptografado
            $foi = true;
            echo "Arquivo <strong>".str_ireplace(URL, "", url($v))."</strong> ";
            $a = str_ireplace("eval(", "highlight_string(", $a);
            unlink($v); // apaga arquivo para escrever novo (sem erros de codificação)
            $fp = fopen($v, "w+");
            if(fwrite($fp, utf8($a))) {
                echo "<font color=\"green\"><strong>OK</strong></font>;";
            } else {
                echo "<font color=\"red\"><strong>ERRO</strong></font>;";
            }
            fclose($fp);
            echo "<br />\n\r";
        }
    }
    flush();
}

if(!$foi) {
    echo "Todos os arquivos já passaram do step 1.<br />\n\r";
}

echo "\n\r<hr />\r\n<h3>STEP 2: Acessando e quebrando o final</h3>";

$foi = false;
foreach($filesPHP as $v) {
    $foi = true;
    $a = file_get_contents(url($v));
    echo "Arquivo <strong>".str_ireplace(URL, "", url($v))."</strong> ";
    $a = decodifica($a);
    $a = html_entity_decode($a);
    $a = trim($a);
    $a = preg_replace("/^(\?\>)/i", "", $a);
    $a = trim($a);
    $a = utf8($a);
    if($a !== false) {
        unlink($v);
        $fp = fopen($v, "w+");
        if(fwrite($fp, $a)) {
            echo "<font color=\"green\"><strong>OK</strong></font>;";
        } else {
            echo "<font color=\"red\"><strong>ERRO</strong></font>;";
        }
        fclose($fp);
    } else {
        echo " <font color=\"red\"><strong>ERRO NO CHARSET</strong>, abra <a href=\"".url($v)."\" target=\"_blank\">".url($v)."</a> e copie o conteúdo dentro do arquivo</font>;";
    }
    echo "<br />\n\r";
    flush();
}

if(!$foi) {
    echo "Todos os arquivos já passaram do step 2.<br />\n\r";
}

echo "\n\r<hr />\r\n<h1>FIM!</h1>";

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: O unico receio pra mim é que se a pessoa apontar a saída pro mesmo lugar da origem, vai sobreescrever tudo. O resto parece interessante.

Comment: Este é o intuito do script, retirar toda a criptografia de todos os documentos que tiver criptografia.. Se estiver com medo, faça uma cópia de segurança, se não ficar da forma que gostar, retorna o backup.